# Full width slider with responsive items inside

Tags: javascript, css, responsive-design

I'm trying to do a slider that have two links inside, the problem is:

This slider have two hexagons inside, they are links, in different window sizes the positioning of this hexagons change and they need to be at same positioning following the image when resizing.

**My jsFiddle:** http://jsfiddle.net/wtkd/7qr5w511/2/

**Fullscreen view:** http://jsfiddle.net/wtkd/7qr5w511/2/embedded/result/

This two hexagons are positioned correctly, but this image still not getting full width, if i put `background-size:100%`in my `<div class="img-slider>` will get full width, but the hexagons don't follow the position, someone can help me to find a way to maintain hexagons positioned at the same point ever?

Answer (score 1):

I guess this is what you wanted. Little number magic and it's done.

```
.carousel .item .hexagon{
  height: 64%;
  left: 9.5%;
  position: absolute;
  top: 1.5%;
  width: 22.5%;
}

.carousel .item .right{
  right: 13.5%;
  height: 64%;
  bottom: 1.8%;
  width: 22.5%;
}
```

and here's 
[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/Biesas/7qr5w511/6/)

Comment: oh my fkcn gods!!! Thank you so much!!! the magic doing `background-size: 100% 100%` helps to! before i'm doing just one `100%`corresponding to width, two 100% getting width and height, perfect!!!!!!!!!!!